# Functional programming and Do loops

Tags: function-construction, random

I'm writing a Monte Carlo simulation. I'm using a `Do` loop to create the different simulations, iterating over different `SeedRandom[]` parameters in my pseudorandom number generator. I'm trying to formulate it as a function that returns a list of correlations that I can then manipulate.

I expect there is a very simple solution, but I have to admit that I'm pretty new to *Mathematica* so I'm having problems. The *Mathematica* documentation seems to conveniently dodge this issue whenever it comes up! This might be a little complicated, so I'll explain what my code does first, then I'll describe the problem precisely.

*First I make a list with the parameters of each of my random variables (I want them to have different means):*

```
varparams = Table[i, {i, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}];
```

*Then I define my random variables:*

```
var[i_]:=RandomChoice[{varparams[[i]],1-varparams[[i]]}->{1,0},10]
```

*(I'm generating [for argument's sake] a set of 10 values for each run of the simulation).*

*Now, I define the function that iterates over different SeedRandom[] values, so as to generate different data sets. I want to calculate a list of correlations:*

```
corrlist = {};
corrcheck[i_, j_, n_] := Do[
  SeedRandom[k];
  AppendTo[corrlist, Correlation[var[i], var[j]]];
  , {k, n}]
```

*(`n` is the number of different runs of the simulation).*

Now this sort of works, in the sense that I can run `corrcheck[i,j,n]` and then work with the `corrlist` that is produced, but what I want is for `corrcheck[i,j,n]` **itself** to be a list, so that I can make tables and other manipulations of `corrcheck` for different values of `i` and `j`. I hope this makes sense. To reiterate: I want the function `corrcheck`, which consists of a `Do` loop, to produce a unique list for each set of `i,j,n`, so that I can do things like:

```
Table[corrcheck[i,j,100],{i,10},{j,10}]
```

and manipulations thereof.

The answer has to be obvious. I just can't see it!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Something like `corrcheck[i_, j_, n_] := Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[k]; Correlation[var[i], var[j]]], {k, n}]` then?

Comment: Wow. I thought it would be easy, but that's really obvious now that I think about it. Thanks! I don't know why I had the idea that a Do[] loop was necessary.

Comment: I'll probably accept that as an answer, if you care to submit it - I can't imagine a simpler solution.

Comment: Tell me if I understood correctly: you want `corrcheck[i_, j_, n_]` to build a list with `n` simulations of correlation (10 samples each) between 2 independent bernoullis with weights defined by `i` and `j`, and you want that function to always return the same output for the same i,j,n ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want(ed).

Comment: @Ooku `Do` loops are not necessarily bad; in fact, their syntax is identical to `Table` - a functional stalwort. When a loop is necessary, `Do` is typically the way to go. The biggest issue with your code is the `AppendTo` command; look into useing `Reap` and `Sow`, rather than `Append` or `AppendTo`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be what you want:

```
corrcheck[i_, j_, n_, opts___] := Table[BlockRandom[
   SeedRandom[k, FilterRules[{opts}, Method]];
   Correlation[var[i], var[j]]], {k, n}]
```

The additional optional argument allows you to change the algorithm used behind the pseudorandom number generator; you can thus do either a call like `corrcheck[7, 10, 100]` if you're happy with the defaults, or `corrcheck[7, 10, 100, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]` if you want to fool around with the Mersenne Twister.