# Constraining a random function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, random

This question is a follow-up from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11171/functional-programming-and-do-loops). I have a function that generates a list of correlations between some random variables:

```
varparams = Table[i, {i, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1}];

var[i_] := 
 RandomChoice[{varparams[[i]], 1 - varparams[[i]]} -> {1, 0}, 10]

corrcheck[i_, j_, n_] := 
 Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[k];  
    Correlation[var[i], var[j]]], {k, n}]
```

Now, if by chance one or both of `var[i]`,`var[j]` is a list of all 1's, then `Correlation[var[i],var[j]]` is undefined. I want to improve `corrcheck[i_, j_, n_]` so that it automatically throws away all such `vars`. My idea was to do something like this:

```
corrcheck[i_, j_, n_] := 
 Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[k]; 
   If[Mean@var[i] != 1 && Mean@var[j] != 1, 
    Correlation[var[i], var[j]], "N/A"]], {k, n}]
```

Why doesn't this work? Have I missed a better alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A minor issue with your current test is that it ignores the case where `Mean[var[i]]=0`. You need to use `Variance[var[i]]` in your condition.

However, this does not fix the real problem. The real issue with the current formulation is that randomization is performed everytime  `var[i]` is used. Because of this, when you check `Variance[var[i]] !=0` and then later use `var[i]` in `Correlation[var[i]],var[j]]` there are actually two different `var[i]`s, and sometimes the first one passes your check but the second one inside `Correlation` has zero standard deviation. To fix this you need to use something like

```
 ClearAll[corrcheck];
 corrcheck[i_, j_, n_] := 
 Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[k]; With[{v1 = var[i], v2 = var[j]},
 If[Variance@v1 != 0 && Variance@v2 != 0, Correlation[v1, v2], "N/A"]]], {k, n}]
```

where in each iteration one random value is generated to be used for checking non-zero variance **and** computing the correlation for each `var[i]`.

EDIT: Few more alternative ways to define `corrcheck`

```
ClearAll[corrcheck2, corrcheck3];
corrcheck2[i_, j_, n_] := Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[k]; 
    Module[{v1, v2}, If[Variance@v1 != 0 && Variance@v2 != 0, Correlation[v1, v2], 
   "N/A"] /. {v1 -> var[i], v2 -> var[j]}]], {k, n}];
corrcheck3[i_, j_, n_] :=   Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[k]; 
  If[Variance@#1 != 0 && Variance@#2 != 0, Correlation[#1, #2], 
   "N/A"] &[var[i], var[j]]], {k, n}];
corrcheck[1, 2, 10]
(* {"N/A","N/A",-0.21821789,"N/A",0.21821789,-0.408248290,
   -0.1111111,-0.3333333,-0.218217,"N/A"}*)
corrcheck2[1, 2, 10] == corrcheck3[1, 2, 10] == corrcheck[1, 2, 10]
(* True *)
```

EDIT: Cleanest approach is to make use of `Correlation`'s internal testing for zero standard deviation -- using `Check` as in Mark's answer but placing it just outside `Correlation`:

```
corrcheckX[i_, j_, n_] := Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[k];
 Quiet[ Check[Correlation[var[i], var[j]], "N/A", Correlation::zerosd]]], {k, n}];
corrcheck2[1, 2, 10]==corrcheck3[1, 2, 10]==corrcheck[1, 2, 10] == corrcheckX[1, 2, 10]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Okay, now we're cooking, but (correct me if I misunderstand your code) it seems I would have to `ClearAll[corrcheck]` every time I want to call `corrcheck[i,j,n]. Is there a way to *include* ClearAll in the function itself?

Comment: @Ooku, you don't need to use `ClearAll[...]` everytime you use `corrcheck[i,j,n]`. You need to use clear only once before you define corrcheck - just in case you previously used the symbol `corrcheck` with other specifications during the current mma session.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks a lot for the prompt reply, btw!

Comment: @Ooku, my pleasure. Welcome to Mma.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use `Check` to check for the error message and return some symbol or string indicating the failure

```
corrcheck[i_, j_, n_] := Quiet[Check[
 Table[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[k];  
  Correlation[var[i], var[j]]], {k, n}],
  "bad",Correlation::zerosd]];
```

Now

```
result = {corrcheck[8,8,1], corrcheck[8,8,2]} // InputForm
(* Out: {{-(1/Sqrt[21])}, "bad"} *)
```

Afterwards, you could call `DeleteCases[result, "bad"]` to delete the bad stuff.

Comment: That works after a fashion, but it maps entire sets of correlations -> bad, instead of just one of the set.